# Tensors and 4-vectors

Tags: tensors

This may be a very trivial question, but help would be appreciated.

It has to do with [P. 55 in these notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/D22Lb.pdf)

I don't understand why the fact that $$U_a\dot U^a=0$$ applied to $$U_a\nabla_b T^{ab}=\rho U_a\dot U^a+U_aU^a\nabla_b (\rho U^b)$$ giving $$U_a\nabla_b T^{ab}=\nabla_b (\rho U^b)$$ (we have taken $U_aU^a=1$) would imply that $$\dot U^a=0$$

Please explain! Thank you.

Comment: You have accidentally created two accounts, which is why you were not able to edit or comment on your post directly. Here is the process to merge your accounts: `From any page footer -> 'contact us' >> 'Merge user profiles'`. Also, if you have figured out your question, then I suggest just writing up the answer yourself and posting it; this is very much allowed and encouraged here.